# Can't see linear gradient svg text in my jade file

Tags: css, svg, less, pug, linear-gradients

I have this question only because this same linear gradient works on another page, same browsers (chrome and firefox). I copied and pasted the following code from one `.jade` file that works to this new one that doesn't:

```
.mycontainer
  svg(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg")
    defs(id="defs")
      linearGradient(id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%")
        stop(offset="0%" id="stop1")
        stop(offset="100%" id="stop2")
    text(fill="url(#grad1)" id="text" x="50%" y="75") THIS TEXT SHOWS UP AS BLACK
```

Actually, whereas `url(#grad1)` worked on the one page, only `url(#defs #grad1)` will display any text at all on this page. But still, not the gradient, just black text. Also, I tried changing `fill="url(#grad1")` to `fill="red"`, and I can see the red text, so it SEEMS to be a problem with the gradient.

I copied the following code from one `.less` file that works to another that doesn't:

```
.mycontainer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  #svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    #defs {
      #grad1 {
        #stop1 {
          stop-color:#00ffff;
          stop-opacity:1;
        }
        #stop2 {
          stop-color:#ff7fff;
          stop-opacity:1;
        }
      }
    }
    #text {
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-size:20px;
    }
  }
}
```

What could explain this? I know when some resources fail to load, that can affect the load of other things. What's weird is that the text shows up, but it's black, not gradient. Remember, I copied and pasted this exact code from 2 other files that go to a web page where this WORKS. Thoughts? (Let me know if more code is needed.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there duplicate ids on the page or are you using a `<base>` tag on the page?

Comment: There are no duplicate ids on the same page. There's a totally separate page with the same ids, but I tried changing all ids, and it still didn't work. And no, no base tag. Thanks for the response! I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough info. I wanted to know first if there was something internally wrong with the above code.

Comment: Can you post the generated file somewhere?

Comment: mmm, how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/e0sptLyq/3/

Comment: Of course, there's more going on here that I think is important. I tried copying and pasting the same stuff from the working page, and text shows up black on that jsfiddle, too. Is there some library i need to reference or something?

Comment: You should compile your Less code into CSS code first, see http://codepen.io/bassjobsen/pen/LENBqK, more about compiling Less at http://lesscss.org/

Comment: It is interesting that it works there. Especially since the code is no different than what I had written. This is what makes me think I'm missing a lib reference or I'm including a conflicting reference.

Comment: Yes, indeed your are missing the Less compile (codepen.io has a built-in Less compiler).

Comment: I already have something that compiles it into css. That's why I didn't have to do it before with the page that works. My question (besides what's causing this), is why I need to add the parent ID into the text url in order to make the text visible at all. That is, instead of just `url(#grad1)`, I need `url(#defs #grad1)`

Comment: EDIT: the text url with jsut the lineargradient ID renders the text completely invisible, but anything else at least makes the text visible (though black). That is, I can't see text with `url(#grad1)`, but I can with `url(x #grad1)`